# Help diagnosing Likewise Open Active Directory authentication problem

Tags: linux, active-directory, likewise-open

I have two servers which were up until recently authenticating against the companies Active Directory Domain controller. I believe a recent change to the Active Directory administrator password caused the servers to stop authenticating against AD. I tried to add the servers back to the domain using the command:

`domainjoin-cli join example.com adusername`

this seemed to work without complaints, but when I try to login via ssh with my domain account, I get an invalid password error. When I run the command:

`lw-enum-users`

it prints all of the domain users, and looking up my own account, I see that it is valid and my password hasn't expired. I also ran

`lw-get-status` and received the following:

`LSA Server Status:`

Agent version: 5.0.0
Uptime:        0 days 3 hours 35 minutes 46 seconds

[Authentication provider: lsa-activedirectory-provider]

```
    Status:        Online
    Mode:          Un-provisioned
    Domain:        example.com
    Forest:        example.com
    Site:          Default-First-Site-Name
    Online check interval:  300 seconds
    \[Trusted Domains: 1\]


    \[Domain: EXAMPLE\]

            DNS Domain:       example.com
            Netbios name:     EXAMPLE
            Forest name:      example.com
            Trustee DNS name:
            Client site name: Default-First-Site-Name
            Domain SID:       S-1-5-24-1081533780-4562211299-822531512
            Domain GUID:      057f0239-7715-4711-e64b-eb5eeed20e65
            Trust Flags:      \[0x001d\]
                              \[0x0001 - In forest\]
                              \[0x0004 - Tree root\]
                              \[0x0008 - Primary\]
                              \[0x0010 - Native\]
            Trust type:       Up Level
            Trust Attributes: \[0x0000\]
            Trust Direction:  Primary Domain
            Trust Mode:       In my forest Trust (MFT)
            Domain flags:     \[0x0001\]
                              \[0x0001 - Primary\]

            \[Domain Controller (DC) Information\]

                    DC Name:              dc1.example.com
                    DC Address:           10.11.0.103
                    DC Site:              Default-First-Site-Name
                    DC Flags:             \[0x000003fd\]
                    DC Is PDC:            yes
                    DC is time server:    yes
                    DC has writeable DS:  yes
                    DC is Global Catalog: yes
                    DC is running KDC:    yes
```

[Authentication provider: lsa-local-provider]

```
    Status:        Online
    Mode:          Local system
```

Anyone got any ideas what might be occurring?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Additional Info: It would appear that this only affects users who have previously logged onto the server. When another AD user logs onto the system for the first time, they are allowed access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved when my current active directory password expired and I had to set a new one. Still unsure why this occurred though...

Answer (score 0):

I work for Likewise Software and was forwarded your request for help. The output you have given looks correct and it looks like a properly joined machine.

Please provide me with the following things so I can try to help you out.

1. OS release (e.g. RHEL 5.3 or Ubuntu 8.10)
2. Version of Likewise Open (run, without quotes, "cat /opt/likewise/data/VERSION" and post results)
3. The contents of /etc/likewise/lsassd.conf  (run, without quotes, "cat /etc/likewise/lsassd.conf" and post results)

Regards,

Yvo van Doorn

Comment: Thanks for your help Yvo.

1. The machine is running Ubuntu 9.10.

2. The folder /opt/likewise doesn't exist, which confused me when reading the documentation. Presumably this is because it's a Ubuntu installation?

3. The conf file was found in /etc/likewise-open5/lsassd.conf, I've removed the lines starting with # for brevity, and pasted the results below:

Comment: /etc/likewise-open5/lsassd.conf
[global]
    domain-separator = \
[pam]
    log-level = error
[auth provider:lsa-activedirectory-provider]
    path = /usr/lib/likewise-open5/liblsass_auth_provider_ad.so
    login-shell-template = /bin/bash
    homedir-template = %H/%D/%U
    ldap-sign-and-seal = false

    cache-entry-expiry = 4h
    machine-password-lifespan = 30d
    space-replacement = ^
    cell-support = unprovisioned
[auth provider:lsa-local-provider]
    path = /usr/lib/likewise-open5/liblsass_auth_provider_local.so
    password-lifespan = 30d
    password-change-warning-time = 14d